# Extracting beats out of MP3 music with Python

Tags: python, video, audio, signal-processing

What kind of solutions are there to analyze beats out of MP3 music in Python? The purpose of this would be to use rhythm information to time the keyframes of generated animation, export animation as video file and and mix the video and audio together.

Comment: Just noticed the "use rhythm information to time the keyframes of generated animation" part. You're making a visualizer of sorts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this:

[The Echo Nest Remix API](http://code.google.com/p/echo-nest-remix/)

```
# You can manipulate the beats in a song as a native python list
beats = audio_file.analysis.beats
beats.reverse()
```

Comment: That's pretty neat, but out of curiosity are there any alternatives that don't require an active internet connection?

Comment: I am not a big fan of bringing in third party to a mix, especially if this is not 100% open source.

Comment: Can we get access to your link? It's posted publicly but I can't get to it without permission.

Comment: @PapaDeBeau it's not my link... it points to a library I found at the time. The link worked then but changed... You can try this instead: http://echonest.github.com/remix/ I think they're the same thing.